# Complex differentials $\Delta z$ or $\Delta x$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

In Schaum's Complex Variables second edition equation 3.9, the limit is given with respect to $\Delta x$ however it was previously given as the limit with respect to $\Delta z$. Is this a typo? If not why is the limit of the complex derivative not with respect to $\Delta z$?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a typo.

Comment: I think this has to be a typo. You are computing the derivative $f'(z)$, so the limit should be as $\delta z\to 0$, exactly as it is in the last quantity in (3.9), and not with respect to $x$.